# How do I get the `.which()` of a particular type in a boost::variant?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, variant

Say I have:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> moog;
```

Given an instance of `moog` I can get the `.which()` for its type, e.g.:

```
moog foo = ...;
foo.which(); //0 for int, 1 for float, 2 for std::string
```

What's the best way to get the `.which()` given the type itself? e.g. something like:

```
moog.MAGIC<int>(); // 0
moog.MAGIC<float>(); // 1
moog.MAGIC<std::string>(); // 2
```

I figure I can instantiate a `moog` and do it that way (untested, example only):

```
template <class Variant, class Which>
size_t MAGIC() {
    Which w;
    Variant foo = w;
    return foo.which(); 
}

MAGIC<moog, int>(); // 0
MAGIC<moog, float>(); // 1
MAGIC<moog, std::string>(); // 2
```

However, this is clunky as it requires instantiating two objects. It also won't work for classes without a default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use C++11:

```
template <std::size_t, typename, typename...> struct find_;

template <std::size_t pos, typename T, typename Other, typename... Args>
struct find_<pos, T, Other, Args...> : find_<pos+1, T, Args...> {};
template <std::size_t pos, typename T, typename... Args>
struct find_<pos, T, T, Args...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, pos> {};
template <std::size_t pos, typename T>
struct find_<pos, T> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::size_t(-1)> {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using find = find_<0, T, Args...>;

template <typename, typename> struct IndexInVariant;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct IndexInVariant<boost::variant<Types...>, T> :
    find<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type, Types...> {};
```

Usage:

```
IndexInVariant< boost::variant<int, float, std::string>, std::string >::value // 2

IndexInVariant< boost::variant<int, float, std::string>, char >::value // -1
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cba315c250bcf43).

Comment: Damn, that is intense... thanks! This will work on linux but it's a cross-platform project, and I'm using MSVC 2012 on Windows, which I don't think will like at least the `using find = find_ ...` line.

Comment: @Claudiu You can replace the alias template by a class template, if necessary.

Comment: Looks like my puppy stepped on my keyboard :D +1, btw

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using boost you might as well use [`boost::mpl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html)

```
#include <boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find.hpp>

template <class Variant, class Which>
size_t MAGIC()
{
  return boost::mpl::distance
         <typename boost::mpl::begin<typename Variant::types>::type,
          typename boost::mpl::find<typename Variant::types, Which>::type
         >::type::value;
}
```

---

### Edit

[P0W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) proposed a version that returns -1 if the type is not found instead of the last index of the `types`sequence which is obviously a better thing:

```
template <class Variant, class Which>
int MAGIC()
{
  size_t pos = boost::mpl::distance
         <typename boost::mpl::begin<typename Variant::types>::type,
          typename boost::mpl::find<typename Variant::types, Which>::type
         >::type::value ;

  size_t last= boost::mpl::distance
         <typename boost::mpl::begin<typename Variant::types>::type,
          typename boost::mpl::end<typename Variant::types>::type
         >::type::value;

         return pos != last ? pos : -1 ;
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but if a type is not available it simple displays the last pos, however can be fixed, I tried [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c63a2b7bbbc825b4), must be some easy coding too.

Comment: But that's not a compile-time solution.

Comment: @IgorR. It can be made `constexpr`.

Comment: @IgorR.I used the format the OP wanted it to be which is a simple template function, but it can become a template structure typedef or templated type alias in c++11 for a compile time check since everything here is known at compile time

Comment: @P0W Thanks, i was thinking of improving this if the op asked for it :)